# Select sister elements of a table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to fill a td element by accessing other td s in the same row.   How would I access them using jQuery?

In my situation, I have a table, and column 5 is populated by subtracting col 3 from col 4, and returning the result in col 5.   I started to do it with a nested loop, but realized, that if I used the .each() on each col 5 td, it would be achievable if I could identify col 3 and 4 using jQuery.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/t2SEF/).

The section to identify the elements is here:

```
$('section.techtable td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
    $(this).append(strinToMonthNumber($(START JQUERY),$(END JQUERY)));
})
```

I think that I would have to access the parent of $(this), and then the (3rd and 4th) child element?

I am also trying to avoid using span or class attributes on the TH or TD elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select one element (table cell in your case), and then use `jQuery.prev()` or `jQuery.next()` to select previous or next sibling element. In native DOM, you could use `previousSibling`/`nextSibling` (or `previousElementSibling`/`nextElementSibling` in modern browsers to skip non-element nodes) element properties for same purpose.

Based on your code example, something like this:

```
$('section.techtable td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
    var cell5 = $(this),
        cell4 = cell5.prev(),
        cell3 = cell4.prev();

    cell5.append(strinToMonthNumber(cell3, cell4)));
})
```

Comment: I couldn't understand his question, but I got the feeling that he's not asking about `prev` and `next`

Comment: what do you need clarification on?

Comment: @gdoron I got the opposite impression - seems like `.prev()` is precisely what he needs, even if it's not what he thought he needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('section.techtable tr').each(function() {
    var $cells = $(this).find("td");
    var val = strinToMonthNumber($cells.eq(2).text(),$cells.eq(3).text());
    $cells.eq(4).text(val);
});
```

Note that the cell indexes are of zero-origin, therefore one less than your 3/4/5. If you already took zero-origin into account, then +1 in each case.